# Is there a similar library as Thrust (parallel STL for GPU), but for GPGPU AMD Radeon?

Tags: c++, stl, opencl, gpgpu

Is there a similar library as Thrust(parallel STL for GPU, which can use OpenMP/TBB, C++ CUDA), but for GPGPU AMD Radeon (eg using OpenCL instead of using CUDA)?
Required standard STL-algorithms (Sort, Merge, Remove/Copy if, In/Exclusive scan, etc), which optimal implemented in parallel in GPU AMD Radeon in Win/*nix (AMP does not fit).

Comment: Check out Boost.Compute: http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/.

Comment: @Kyle Lutz  Thanks! And with how many times faster sorting(stable_sort) on GPGPU compared to the CPU with the same price? For example, in Thrust(STL for CUDA GPU) thrust::stable_sort 5 times faster than CPU(Core i7) with the same price.

Comment: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SyclParallelSTL sits on top of SYCL, which sits on top of OpenCL, which is well-supported on AMD hardware.

Comment: These days there is rocThrust from AMD. (not sure of an true Thrust-compatible alternative for Intel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMD provide Bolt C++ Template Library. That lib will support both AMP and OpenCL as backend.

http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/bolt-c-template-library/

Comment: But why does it support only Win7/8 (this is writen in article by your link), and not support any of *nix-OS if it uses OpenCL(which cross-platform)?

Comment: I don't know, I only know it exist :)

Comment: Bolt works on Linux now https://github.com/HSA-Libraries/Bolt/releases/tag/v1.1GA